# Electron : Open hash link in the same page

Tags: angular, electron

I'm developing a desktop app from a website I made. The website is using Angular.

This app use hash link to navigate in long text (titles are identified with id and HTML anchors are used to go to the title). The anchor is defined like this :

```html
<div> long text </div>

<a href="#example">Example headline</a>

<div> more long text </div>

<h1 id="example">Example headline</h1>

<div> again more long text </div>
```

In a browser, with the webpage, it's working correctly. By clicking on it, the browser scroll to the correct tag.

Electron does not handle to hash links. When the user click on the same link, the electron app sends the error : [image: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///home/auriel/Documents/Projects/html-handbook-v3-electron/dist/#TODO_List]
I don't know how to get the same behaviour : How to scroll to the correct element without reloading the page (reloading the page will cause performance issues).

I found several solutions on StackOverFlow but none apply to my case.

My current idea is to define a custom anchor. When the user clicks on it, the anchor calls a function with `windows.scroll` function (I have to manage to find the position of the target). But I imagine there is more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Are you using loadURL or loadFile?

Comment: I'm using `url.loadURL` with `file` protocol. I load one time the page at the beggining.